# 1 vs. 2 balun(s) on extension cable

Tags: antenna, rfid, balun

I am quite new to SDR and RF learning and experimenting.

I am trying to build an extension cable to relay an RFID signal (125kHz) to various distances (2,5,10m). I am using 2 identical [antennas](https://www.tme.eu/it/details/ant125k-45/antenne-rf/eccel/)  at the two ends of the coax cable, and I also put 2 identical [baluns](https://www.nooelec.com/store/balun-one-nine.html) between the antennas and the cable ends.
By using HackRF coupled with HamItUp, I was able to verify that the signal from the rfid emitter does seem to reach the end of the cable with seemingly identical waveform and amplitudes; however, when the passive element of the RFID is put in the proximity of the antenna (<2cm), it is not recognized.

Where should I start investigating the problem? Perhaps I have misunderstood the function of the baluns, and they are not needed in this setup? Or perhaps just one?

Comment: what did you expect the baluns to do? ... what is the cable that are you using? ... how did you connect the baluns?

Comment: `Perhaps I have misunderstood the function of the baluns, and they are not needed in this setup` ... have you tested it without the baluns? ... one balun?

Comment: my understanding is that baluns should be inserted between an unbalanced (coax) an a balanced (antenna?) circuits. I connected both baluns to the coax cable end and the antennas. That's precisely what I was asking: should I or should I not insert baluns into the described circuit?

Comment: You need a balun between a balanced and unbalanced circuit, but the balun also needs to match the impedance of one circuit to that of the other, so you can't just stick any random one to anything and expect it to work. Also, the system you described has no gain, so I'm not sure how you're intending to use it as a repeater.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. The coax cable I am using is 75ohm; as for the balun, I'm not sure, . the1 description just states "1:9", which, to my understanding, is the transformation factor (?). As for the gain, I didn't add an amplifier just because the SDR reading at the remote end shows negligible loss in  signal strength; however, in case I should add an amplifier, what would be the parameters I should look for?